# How to get line number of the newly modified lines when we save a file in vs code workspace?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a vs code extension.
I am trying to find a VS Code Extension API or any other way which will tell the line number of newly modified lines
added/updated saved by user in a file in vscode workspace.

For example: If Test.js file is opened in VSCode workspace having following content:

```
export class **App** {
  constructor() {
    this.html = "<h1>DomSanitizer</h1><script>attackerCode()</script>"
  }
}
```

Then user modifies the content to as shown below and saves it:

```
export class **Application** {
  constructor() {
    this.html = "<h1>DomSanitizer</h1><script>attackerCode()</script>"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get the line number which was modified? For eg: In above example App was modified to Application,
so the output should be line number 1.

Answer (score 0):

There's a onDidChangeTextDocument event that you can use. It's in vscode.workspace:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace

---

The event parameter that is sent to the callback is called TextDocumentChangeEvent :

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocumentChangeEvent

This event holds the TextDocument(see bottom of post) that was changed and an array of TextDocumentContentChangeEvents:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocumentContentChangeEvent

From this array is where you get the line numbers that were changed. The TextDocumentContentChangeEvent holds a Range class variable that gives you the start and end positions of what lines were changed.  Since you only care about the line number and not where in the line it was modified you'd just use the start/end Position line variables.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Range

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Position

---

For when a text document is saved, you can use the onDidSaveTextDocument in vscode.workspace:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace

This sends a TextDocument to the callback:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument